# Go to step in Pardot Engagement Studio

Tags: pardot

There is a complex engagement program in Pardot. After certain yes/no equations, prospect reaches to a certain stage. From this stage on a particular action we want to take him/her to an earlier/previous step which is way above from his current step.

I know there is a 'go to step' in ActOn, however couldn't find anything in Pardot to go to a previous step.

Here is an example:

List - send email - click on email link (yes/no) - if yes, go to step 1, if no go to step 2 - from step 1 if he fills a form (yes/no) - if yes go to step 3, else go to step 4 - from step 4 if he fills another form (yes/no) - if yes go to step 5, else go to step 6.
(now from step 6, I want to take him/her to step 2)

Comment: This is not possible in Pardot but there might be workarounds for your usecase. Would you mind sharing in more detail what you would like to achieve?

Comment: There are ways to accomplish the goal without the named 'jump' steps. I can make something up and take a screen shot, but it's probably more meaningful to you see examples to your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Fred and creuzerm. Managed for now. Will share if something arises. Would you mind looking at this issue - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/285235/65967